# parallax with 100% height divs

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

Currently I am using backstretch (http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) with smooth scroll to anchor to 100% height sections of my one page website. I am trying to incorporate stellar.js parallax (http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) but am having all kinds of problems. Is there an easy way to make this work with 100% height divs? I have 4 divs with heights of 100% and would like them to scroll at different speeds. Currently I am running stellar against the window.

HTML

```
<div class="main-container" data-stellar-ratio="0.5">
<div class="main-container2" data-stellar-ratio="2">
<div class="main-container3" data-stellar-ratio="0.5">
<div class="main-container4" data-stellar-ratio="2">
```

CSS

```
.main-container {
background-image:url(../images/footballfieldblur.jpg);
min-height:100%;
height:100%;
z-index:-100;
position:relative;

}
.main-container2 {
background-image:url(../images/orange3.png);
min-height:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;

}
.main-container3 {
background-image:url(../images/lightbackground.jpg);
min-height:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;

}
.main-container4 {
background-image:url(../images/gopherbackground.png);
min-height:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
}
```

Javascript (backstretch.js)

```
<script>
// You may also attach Backstretch to a block-level element

$(".main-container").backstretch("images/footballfieldblur.jpg");
$(".main-container2").backstretch("images/orange3.png");
$(".main-container3").backstretch("images/lightbackground.jpg");
$(".main-container4").backstretch("images/gopherbackground.png");
</script>
```

Parallax (stellar.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(window).stellar(); 
      horizontalScrolling:false 
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't have experience with this particular plug in but I have a few questions for you - are you using using the slideshow facility of the jQuery plugin or are you simply using it to add an background image to cover the areas (whether they are backgrounds or divs)?

Comment: Doug I am using it to add background images to cover the areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason why don't you just use straight forward CSS?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uzKFu/1/

Basically, support for `background-size` is pretty good these days.

Try resizing the pane sizes in the fiddle to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

did you make a mistake copying the code? cause the js should throw an error. If you use firebug on ff or chrome dev tool you'll be able to see the error in the console. 
I believe "horizontalScrolling:false" belongs to the stellar() method as a config parameter like this -

```
$(window).stellar({horizontalScrolling:false});
```

I don't have any prior experience with stellar.js so can't say for sure that this will fix your issue.